# Which implementation in JPA should be followed to optimize the login

Tags: java, class, frameworks, uml

[image: A class diagram]

Hey guys, I'm having a doubt about the implementation of class diagram above, confused between the Single_table strategy and the joined_table strategy, any help, any suggestion about the patterns followed in this case that are used to enhance the response time of the login process.
Any help will be appreciated. 
  Thank you guys in advance :).

Comment: You probably need to elaborate what your doubt is.

Comment: Alas, what concern should one have to "optimize" a login as if that were a transaction performed 100,000 times a second?

Comment: i did @ThomasKilian, not sure whether using one table for all users or one table for class

Comment: Ok, thanks @ThomasKilian, i'll go with the single table strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right your concern is whether to us a table `User`  with a flag of different `Professor` etc. tables. Well, I'd go for the single table. Actually there is not much difference in performance. In order to retrieve the professors from the user table you would need a `WHERE` clause while a native table has the records ready. The time difference in any case would be near to null as a RDBMS will handle `WHERE` clauses very effectively granted the DBA has set good indices. A single table is easier to maintain with respect to maintaining all the columns you need (but which your class diagram currently does not show).